# What is the magic behind perl read() function and buffer which is not a ref?

Tags: perl, io, buffer, handle

I do not get to understand how the Perl read($buf) function is able to modify the content of the $buf variable. $buf is not a reference, so the parameter is given by copy (from my c/c++ knowledge). So how come the $buf variable is modified in the caller ?

Is it a tie variable or something ? The C documentation about setbuf is also quite elusive and unclear to me

```
# Example 1
$buf=''; # It is a scalar, not a ref
$bytes = $fh->read($buf);
print $buf; # $buf was modified, what is the magic ?

# Example 2
sub read_it {
    my $buf = shift;
    return $fh->read($buf);
}
my $buf;
$bytes = read_it($buf);
print $buf; # As expected, this scope $buf was not modified
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No magic is needed -- all perl subroutines are call-by-alias, if you will.  Quoth [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html):

> The array @_ is a local array, but its elements are aliases
>   for the actual scalar parameters.  In particular, if an element $_[0]
>   is updated, the corresponding argument is updated (or an error occurs
>   if it is not updatable).

For example:

```
sub increment {
  $_[0] += 1;
}

my $i = 0;
increment($i);  # now $i == 1
```

In your "Example 2", your `read_it` sub *copies* the first element of `@_` to the lexical `$buf`, which copy is then modified "in place" by the call to `read()`.  Pass in `$_[0]` instead of copying, and see what happens:

```
sub read_this {
  $fh->read($_[0]);  # will modify caller's variable
}
sub read_that {
  $fh->read(shift);  # so will this...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer to the relevant doc, and your trick works, great thanks

Answer (score 0):

`read()` is a built-in function, and so can do magic. You can accomplish something similar with your own functions, though, by declaring a [function prototype](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes):

```
sub myread(\$) { ... }
```

The argument declaration `\$` means that the argument is implicitly passed as a reference.

The only magic in the built-in `read` is that it works even when called indirectly or as a filehandle method, which doesn't work for regular functions.

Comment: You don't need a prototype or explicit passing-by-reference in order to modify a variable passed to a subroutine: `sub foo { $_[0] ++ }`.

Comment: +1  This isn't quite on point for the OP's question, but prototypes and *bona fide* perl references (not symbolic refs) are important to know in this domain.

Comment: @FM, good catch. I always forget that `@_` can be used that way.